# How can I add TeamViewer to the list of startup entries in Task Manager via registry/properly (not using startup folder)?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, teamviewer

I realize you can add it to the startup folder, but i'm trying to mirror the functionality that would exist if it were there by default (like most softwares - sigh).

For example, anydesk (same as TV) the service will always run regardless.   However the tray icon/client.exe is only present if you have the item set to enabled in Taskmanager>startup.

Teamviewer offers a checkbox within the client itself to mimic the same functionality (most have both, taskmanager entry seems to supersede whats set in the client best i can tell).

I'd prefer to have it in the Task manager as well.

I'm familiar with reg locations such as

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved\Run
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

etc.  However I have no idea which locations it needs to be added, and what the values need to be.  I of  course want it to start silently to the tray, same as if it would by using the gui checkbox.

i tested via the startup folder and it starts wide open, and even as a shortcut with minimize set it would start minimized to taskbar, not tray.

anyone able to point me in the proper direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *installed* it on your PC, as opposed to using it as portable ("run only" in the install window), then you're in the right place.

In the right pane of your Registry Editor window, just right-click > New > String, call it TeamViewer, press Enter to validate, Enter again to open it, and point to the executable in the target box.

The executable itself should be in Program Files (x86), under TeamViewer. That or in your AppData folder under your user name, in Local, I think.

You can also copy *a shortcut* of TeamViewer.exe in your Startup folder (shell:startup in the Run box), with the attribute you want in terms of window appearance (normal, minimized, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the conventional location whether it be via startup folder, or via registry edit is the answer.

no idea where teamviewer itself is hiding the option (associated with the box in the gui) but to obtain my intended behavior adding it to the startup folder with the the command line parameter --Minimize will ship it to the tray on startup and provide an entry in the task manager.